# Is it possible to obtain a DBA privelege at AWS Oracle?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, amazon-rds

I've created a Oracle DB instance in Amazon cloud. I need to be able to create programmatically a db schema and an owner for this schema. How this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you have credentials of a user which has permissions to create schema and user; u should be able to do this.

Programmatically create a JDBC Connection using that user; and execute same SQL Query just like you would do on TOAD.

Answer (score -1):

When you create a DB in Amazon RDS, you also have to specify the credentials of the DB administrator. You can then use those credentials to connect to the DB instance and perform any administration tasks. You may also connect using those credentials and create more users with dba privileges.

There are restrictions in AWS RDS that you would not be able to do (e.g. RMAN is not supported, or Java XA is disabled and you cannot enable it, etc.). But if all you need is to programmatically create DB schemas, there are no restrictions on that.